# Showing the title of every post in the slider (wordpress)

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to show the title of the post when the images in the slider changes and i am using this code:

```
<div class="form">
    <span>
        <?php
        if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
            echo '<p>' . the_title() . '</p>';
        }
        ?>
    </span>
</div>
```

and

```
$('.slider-section').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
    $('.form span').show(300);
    $('.form').css({
        "display": "block"
    });
});
```

it is only showing the title of the first image, how do i fix it to work on all the images ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `.form` is in `.slider-section` do

```
$('.slider-section').on('afterChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide){
                $(this).find('.form span').show(300);
                $(this).find('.form').css({"display": "block"});
    });
```